# Blog not rendering using middleman

Tags: ruby, github-pages, middleman

I created a middleman blog using [this tutorial](http://ryanswapp.com/2015/02/26/build-a-blog-with-middleman-and-host-on-github-pages/) and [documentation](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging/). Since I had an older blog, I copied few of my posts and pasted into source folder.

Now when I start server, I don't see any of my posts. Can someone help me with this?

Latest code is hosted on [github-pages](https://github.com/aniruddhabarapatre/aniruddhabarapatre.github.io/tree/source/source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this one by moving my posts to source/blog folder.

My `config.rb` I had following set up as -

```
blog.prefix = "blog"
```

Hence, it was looking into blog folder for articles. Moving them resolved my issue.